# Unable to get, insert data from Database with codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am trying the new codeigniter 4
Trying to create first app following tutorial
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

My controller method to insert data

```
public function create()
{
    $model = new NewsModel();

    if (! $this->validate([
        'title' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[255]',
        'body'  => 'required'
    ])) {
        echo view('templates/header', ['title' => 'Create a news item']);
        echo view('news/create');
        echo view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $model->save([
            'title' => $this->request->getVar('title'),
            'slug'  => url_title($this->request->getVar('title'), '-', true),
            'body'  => $this->request->getVar('body'),
        ]);

        echo view('news/success');
    }
}
```

It is echoing success page but data not inserting into database.

In .env file I used

```
 database.default.hostname = localhost
 database.default.database = news_db
 database.default.username = root
 database.default.password =
 database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
```

I think db connection working as checked with wrong database details its not working

My model is

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class NewsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'news';

    protected $allowedFields = ['title', 'slug', 'body'];

    public function getNews($slug = false)
    {

        if ($slug === false) {
            return $this->findAll();

        }

        return $this->asArray()
            ->where(['slug' => $slug])
            ->first();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the error log of apache for linux ubuntu usually is /var/log/apache2/{name_of_error_log} to see if there is an error. Also check if save method returns true. $response = $model->save([]); var_dump($response);

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely coming from your Model declaration in the  Controller.

```
$model = new NewsModel();
```

It should be namespaced.

Try:

```
$model = new \App\Models\NewsModel();
```

or

```
$model = model('NewsModel');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting that:
if you haven't  you should follow the tutorial strictly by extending the core  controller because you did not show that in your code.

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class News extends Controller

And You didnt use App\Models\NewsModel;
Before instantiating your Model class.  You can only do that in the way Ali-coder illustrate.
Again still suggesting you should have use

$request->getPost()
Instead of $this->request->getVar('title')
I am suggesting all this because that is how i wrote mine and it work fine.